# 弾を飛ばして、ぶつかった弾同士がくっつく動作を実現したい

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity4入門書で詰まっているところを質問させてください。
鶏オブジェクトを弾として飛ばして、弾同士があたったらくっ付く、というJavaコードをC#で入力したのですが、弾同士がぶつかるだけで弾いて普通に落ちていってしまいます。

鶏弾をfab化して、このscriptを付け足し、publicのforceとtorqueに70,120を入力。
ちゃんとヒットが成立し、コンポーネントにデータが代入されたか確認するためPrintでデバックをした結果、70,120と設定した値が無事表示されました。
それでもCharacterJointが作れてないのか、分離して落ちていきます。どうすればよいでしょうか。

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StickBall : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float force;
    public float torque;
    private CharacterJoint myjoint;
    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
        {
            if (myjoint == null)
            {
                myjoint = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterJoint>();
                myjoint.connectedBody = other.rigidbody;

                myjoint.breakForce = force;
                myjoint.breakTorque = torque;
                print("breakForce=\n" + gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterJoint>().breakForce);
                print("breakTorque=\n" + gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterJoint>().breakTorque);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 返事が遅れました、申し訳ありません。CharacterJointをFixedJointに変更した場合、二つの弾は引っ付くようになりましたが、近距離の場合はぶつかって跳ね返るだけでした。Mathf.Infinityを設定すると近距離でも無事引っ付くことが

Comment: 近距離でも無事引っ付く動作が実現できました。良いデバッグ方を教えてもらいました、ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決方法を回答として投稿してみてはいかがでしょうか。もしくは役に立った回答を承認すると良いでしょう

Answer (score 1):

[`breakForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/ScriptReference/Joint-breakForce.html)は「接続を解除するために必要な力」、[`breakTorque`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/ScriptReference/Joint-breakTorque.html)は「接続を解除するために必要なトルク」なので、CharacterJointを作っても衝突した時点の値以上の力・回転がかかるとまた離れてしまいます。弾の発射速度が大きいために、衝突時点ではまだ弾が加速中ということはないでしょうか。

デバッグ方法として、`breakForce`と`breakTorque`の両方に`Mathf.Infinity`を設定してみることが考えられます。

それで弾がくっつくようであれば、あとは望みの動作にするために弾の発射速度とのバランス調整や、`breakForce`と`breakTorque`を衝突時点の値より大きくするなど考えられます。

Answer (score 0):

まず、そのCharacterJointはつながってるんですよね？
このJointはバネみたいなもんだから、伸びた状態で着地して止まったのでは？

FixedJointではどうでしょう？